# Passing multiple variables from local bash to remote bash script without gobbling

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm having trouble sending multiple variables to a remote bash script without gobbling occurring.

For the sake of this question the variable $timestamp contains `12-12-15 19:45:21`

```
ssh user@serverip "/usr/path/to/script.sh http://www.web.com/$1 http://web.com/$2 $timestamp";
```

I am sending 3 variables to script.sh

Two URLs with an amended file name in the form of a variable on the end and then my $timestamp variable

But on myscript.sh, when I try to insert $timestamp into a mysql database it only see's the first part of the date before the white space :

```
12-12-15
```

So my quotes around the command aren't preventing gobbling. Do I need to quote each variable separately?

Comment: Probably the space in your timestamp is the problem.  Add single quotes around `$timestamp` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Nope, still only receiving the first part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh user@serverip "/usr/path/to/script.sh http://www.web.com/$1 http://web.com/$2 $timestamp";
```

This is equivalent to this locally calling

```
/usr/path/to/script.sh http://www.web.com/$1 http://web.com/$2 $timestamp
```

Try to quote each individual argument passed

```
ssh user@serverip "/usr/path/to/script.sh 'http://www.web.com/$1' 'http://web.com/$2' '$timestamp'";
```

You can also print each argument in the script to see what's being passed... e.g. `echo $1`, etc.

Comment: Thank you Peter, this what exactly what I needed. I tried quoting everything before but without mixing the single and double quotes. Thanks man!

Comment: The reason you need both sets of quotes is that your shell parses, applies, and then removes the outer level (the double-quotes), passes the result to `ssh`, which passes that to a remote shell, and *that* parses (and removes) the inner level (single-quotes in this example), and then the remote shell passes the result of that to `script.sh`. With only one level of quotes, it was unquoted by the time the remote shell parsed it, and hence got split.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
ssh localhost "printf \"%s %s %s\n\" a b \"last parameter\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the values for the remote host. The correct way of doing this is with `printf %q`:

```
ssh user@serverip "/usr/path/to/script.sh \
    $(printf "%q " "http://www.web.com/$1" "http://web.com/$2" "$timestamp")"
```

This works for all variable values. Wrapping them in single quotes would instead result in syntax error and command injection when the variables themselves contain single quotes.